# dompdf one image not displaying

Tags: php, dompdf

I am running a while loop and generating a var called $features

```
while(blah) {

    $features .= "<li><img src='/srv/sitename.com/htdocs/images/sid.gif'> $features_bullet_text</li>";

} // THIS LOOP WORKS FINE, PULLING CONTENT, IMAGE DOES NOT SHOW
```

Then I am putting this var inside the code below. The content being pulled works fine but the image does not display. The image marked below "IMAGE SHOWS UP" is there when the PDF is generated along with several others but for some reason the one I tacked on to the front of my `<li>` will not show up. Anyone have any suggestions?

It is not permissions, the file path is correct on the server but I need to generate this mysql/loop of `<li>`s prior to putting into this PDF. Hope this makes sense to someone.

```
$html = <<<EOF

PROPER HTML ABOVE

<!-- IMAGE SHOWS UP -->
<img src="/srv/sitename.com/htdocs/images/ordering_information.jpg">

<!-- IMAGE DOES NOT SHOW UP IN LI -->
<ul>
$features
</ul>

PROPER HTML BELOW

EOF;
```

All features working properly. Only the image inside the `<li>` will not show. Also I have tried using double quotes and escaping them and that did not work. Tried no quotes around image and currently have single quotes in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=156), the GD library may need to be installed to display GIF images.

If you can't install that, try replacing your GIF with a JPG or PNG and see if that solves things.